# prolog running not work properly

Tags: prolog

sometimes when I run my program it works properly and sometimes when I try to run it 
it can't start to run
`ERROR: Undefined procedure`:
I restarted
I consulted
then I tried and I got answers
 what is the problem here? what should i do?
I have SWI-Prolog Editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must re-consult the file after adding any rule. Otherwise prolog will not get the rule definition and show `ERROR: Undefined procedure`. You can also do it by using the menu option `Reload modified files`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SWI-Prolog Editor you have to press `F9` to reconsult the file you are currently editing.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl C+Ctrl B does for me: it prompts to save any edited file and run make/0. It's a combination I use so often, has become almost a 'tic' for me...